# Get GCC includes and defines by using API

Tags: python, gcc

Is there a way to get GCC default includes and defines by calling an API? I will use Python to do this (if it's possible) but I'm sure it doesn't matter which language.

Comment: Try `echo | gcc -dM -E -` and `gcc -print-search-dirs`

Comment: @n.m., it's the commandline solution, I need to use an API.

Comment: Command line is the API for gcc.